# Kivy: How to use Clock.Schedule properly in this instance

Tags: python, kivy

So I am working on some code to randomly send keypress's through Virtual Keys after a random timeframe (5-10 seconds is just for testing purposes). I'm trying to add Clock.schedule_once, but with how I have things right now, it is firing off every second because it's stuck in a while loop. I've been wracking my brain around on this one trying to figure out how to implement this properly, but I can't seem to come up with something, so I am reaching out to you guys to see if you can provide any input on possible solutions to this.

```
    def v_key_timer(self, timer, wnd):
        while timer > 0:
            vkey = self.char2key(self.get_char_key(randrange(1, 5)))
            intrvl = randrange(5, 10)  # Sets a random time between 1-4 minutes to do a keypress
            self.select_window(wnd)
            if (timer - intrvl) <= 0:
                win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), 0, 0)  # Keypress Down
                time.sleep(.5)
                win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # Keypress Up
                time.sleep(timer)
                timer = 0
            else:
                win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), 0, 0)  # Keypress Down
                time.sleep(.5)
                win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # Keypress Up
                time.sleep(intrvl)
                timer -= intrvl
```

What I want in the log run is for the user to input a time they would like this to run for, and for it to create a countdown timer for the user to see, but before that, I need to change how this current timer system I have set up is functioning and I figured Clock.Schedule would probably be the best bet, as now, while the time.sleep is running, the program won't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should avoid using time.sleep() in kivy app, because it freezes event handling routines.

Here is my proposal based on two scheduled jobs. In short key pressing job is scheduled once after random time and it reschedules itself indefinitely. Second scheduled job is responsible for stop key pressing job.

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from datetime import datetime
from random import randrange


class Screens(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyScreen(Screen):
    # scheduled job instance
    v_key_timer_job = None
    # window name
    v_key_timer_window = None

    def v_key_timer(self, timer, wnd):
        self.v_key_timer_window = wnd
        if self.v_key_timer_job is None:
            print(f'Key timer for "{self.v_key_timer_window}" started for {timer} seconds')
            # update buttons state
            self.ids.start_button.disabled, self.ids.abort_button.disabled = True, False
            # schedule next key press
            self.v_key_timer_job = Clock.schedule_once(self.v_key_timer_do, randrange(5, 10))
            # schedule end of timer
            Clock.schedule_once(self.v_key_timer_end, timer)

    def v_key_timer_end(self, dt):
        if self.v_key_timer_job is not None:
            print('Key timer stopped')
            # update buttons state
            self.ids.start_button.disabled, self.ids.abort_button.disabled = False, True
            # unschedule v_key_timer_job
            self.v_key_timer_job.cancel()
            self.v_key_timer_job = None

    def v_key_timer_do(self, dt):
        print(f'\t{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")} Doing {self.v_key_timer_window} keypress')
        # vkey = self.char2key(self.get_char_key(randrange(5, 10)))
        # self.select_window(self.v_key_timer_window)
        # win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), 0, 0)  # Keypress Down
        # win32api.keybd_event(vkey, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vkey, 0), win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # Keypress Up
        # schedule next key press
        self.v_key_timer_event = Clock.schedule_once(self.v_key_timer_do, randrange(5, 10))


class KeyTimer(App):
    pass


KeyTimer().run()
```

And kv file:

```
# keytimer.kv

Screens:
    MyScreen:

<MyScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            Label:
                text: 'timer [s]'
            TextInput:
                id: timer
                text: '60'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            Label:
                text: 'wnd'
            TextInput:
                id: wnd
                text: 'window_name'

        Button:
            id: start_button
            text: "Start key timer"
            on_release: root.v_key_timer(int(timer.text), wnd.text)
        Button:
            id: abort_button
            disabled: True
            text: "Abort key timer"
            on_release: root.v_key_timer_end(None)
```

Comment: I haven't been home to look at this, but thank you for your response!

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was able to get it working with Clock.schedule_once now. This was very helpful to learn from.